# Cloud function is writing NaN to firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, nan, google-cloud-firestore

I created a cloud Function to update a following count every time there is a new follower. However, for whatever reason, `NaN` gets written to the document instead of an incremented count. What is `NaN` and why is it getting written instead of the appropriate number? This is my code:

```
var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
    return t.get(countRef)
        .then(doc => {
            var new_count = doc.data.following_count + 1;
            t.update(countRef, { following_count: new_count });
        });
}).then(result => {
    console.log('Transaction success!');
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
});
```

Comment: NaN is "not a number", you're trying to add `1` to something, probably `undefined`. Check the value of `doc.data.following_count`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: @Phix you're right. I am getting undefined. I suppose I am getting my value incorrectly. Back to the drawing board i suppose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NaN is *[Not a Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)*. As some commenters said (but without actually posting an answer), this is caused by operations on non-numeric input, such as undefined values or strings.

Comment: How to roll back the operation that sets the value to its previous value