# How to roll back an operation in cloud firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I created a cloud Function to update a field in a document in my database.But I the actual value got replaced with NaN I know the what is it from this link  [Cloud function is writing NaN to firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797377/cloud-function-is-writing-nan-to-firestore) . But I want to roll back the operation so that the field gets its value back.How is it possible?

Comment: Can you check if the value is a number, before you attempt to write it?  Maybe you could add some sample code to your question.

Comment: Yes, it is a number.

Comment: @JasonBerryman , Lets think it is not a number and the value was replaced with NaN after the operation,as I realised the error I want to roll back the opeartion to its original value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attempt to write the new update.  If it succeeds, your `.then` can resolve the promise and the function can end.  If it fails, add some lines to the `.catch` to update the document with `change.before.data()`

The document will then return to its previous value.

Here is some sample code

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('myCollection/{myDocumentId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {

  const newValue = change.after.data();
  const oldValue = change.before.data();
  
  let myChanges = {
    // Update a value
  };
  
  return change.after.ref.update(myChanges)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Document updated successfully');
      return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // The update failed and the document needs to be rolled back
      return change.before.ref.set(oldValue);
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Document was rolled back');
      return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
});
```